# io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error for above lollipop devices

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I was trying to connect URL (**wws://www.abc.com/ws?sid=sessionId0&mobile=1**) through WebSocket library **socket.io** in android. I am testing with android 5.1 phone. I got the following error as **"io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error"**

Note: I studied that socket.io library is not supporting **wws** security connections from and above lollipop devices.

```
 String url = "wws://www.abc.com/ws?sid=sessionId0&mobile=1";

 mSocket = IO.socket(url);
 mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
 mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
 mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
 mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
 mSocket.connect();




private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.e(TAG, "socket is connected");
            if (!isConnected) {
                if (null != mUsername)
                    mSocket.emit("add user", mUsername);
                isConnected = true;
            }
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            isConnected = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "SOCKET is disconnected");
        }
    };


    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error occurred while connecting to socket");
        }
    };
```

How can I solve my problem. Suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: yes. used retrofit library for socket connection.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add internet permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```